# security issues in Login registration system using php javascript mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, security, encryption

I am building a web application from scratch that has registration and login functionality. I am completely a novice when it comes to security issues and attack like mysql injection. Apart from encryption of password in database, what are other security issues that i have to worry about?? And how do i take care of them??
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure to sanitize all variables in your SQL, if you're not using something like PDO this is done most easily with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

For example, when you are checking a users credentials your code would look something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' AND `password` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'";
$dosql = mysql_query($sql); // etc
```

It's also worth adding the following to your login routine to prevent [session fixation](http://shiflett.org/articles/session-fixation).

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Comment: And if you're passing in an integer instead of a string, don't use `mysql_real_escape_string`, rather, cast it first, like `(int)$myInt`

Answer (score 1):

One thing you really need to look out for is [Cross-site Request Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) (CSRF or XSRF). The easiest way to prevent it is to send a token with each request (even sending a copy of the login cookie will work).

Answer (score 1):

You also have to worry about Cross-Site Scripting attacks. (Often shortened to XSS) Basically, it means that if your application ever makes data submitted by the user part of the HTML of a subsequent page, it must be sanitized. For example, if your application was a message board, a malevolent user could put up a post with embedded HTML that would load a remote javascript without the user's knowledge.

A simple way to defend against it is to encode any data that is made part of the HTML of your web application using a function that encodes HTML characters into entity codes. In PHP, you can use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

However, there's really a lot more you should consider. OWASP (The Open Web Application Security Project) is the industry group that really creates the standards in this area. They publish the [OWASP Top Ten](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007) list, a list of the 10 most prevalent security vulnerabilities. You'll see everything mentioned in of these answers listed there.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "login security issues," there are a number of good articles.  This one is great: [most common security mistakes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325862/what-are-the-most-common-security-mistakes-programmers-make).  Go through every single answer that has a vote and make sure you know what it means and that you're not making that mistake.  In short, to be secure, you must assume every piece of data from a user could be malicious.